Replace (~) with Double Quote (") in C#
I have a string that is in an array. I am trying to find all the ~ tilde chars in a string and replace them with " double quote. This is a conversion, and I had to replace all the " with ~ to make the parser work.
Here is my code:
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
{
    row[i] = Regex.Replace(row[i], "~", "\"");        
}

The string is coming across as:
~~Generator~~

The result I am looking for would be:
""Generator""

This line of code:
row[i] = Regex.Replace(row[i], "~", "\"");

is returning the following result:
"\"\"GENERATOR\"\""

I have also tried this line of code as well:
row[i] = row[i].Replace("~", "\"");

This gives me the result of:
"\"\"GENERATOR\"\""

I have tried to look up other answers, and none of them really fit what I was trying to do.

That looks like exactly the result it should be producing, no?  What exactly isn't working as expected?  If the problem is those backslashes, how are you observing or using this string?

~~Generator~~ is the original string, and I want it to be ""Generator"" without any of the escape characters in there like it is producing

In that case your code works.  The problem is likely in however you're observing or using the result, which you haven't specified.  Please update the question to include a [mcve] which can be independently tested and which demonstrates the problem you are trying to describe.

When in doubt: Try to open the file in Notepad or use Console.WriteLine().

You are right very sorry for the stupid question!!

This is how it is shown in debugger (with escape character \):

but if you would print the character, it would show as you would expect:

By the way, you can simplify your code to:
row = row.Select(x => x.Replace("~", "\"")).ToArray();


The issue you're encountering arises because in C# the backslash \ is an escape character. This means that when you include \" in a string, it represents a literal double quote " character.
string[] row = { "~~Generator~~" };
for(int i=0;i<row.Length; i++)
{
   row[i] = row[i].Replace("~", "\"");
}
Console.WriteLine(row[0]);


Alternatively, use the overload of String.Replace() that takes Chars instead of Strings, then you don't have to worry about the escaping in this example (and its more efficient), eg: row[i] = row[i].Replace('~', '"');
